# How can I access the PSI in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

In my IntelliJ Idea Plugin I can t access the PSI out of my EchoSocketclass(that implements WebSocketListener) after receiving a Message.

I always get this Error:

Read access is allowed from event dispatch thread or inside read-action only... 
By pushing a button, I can access without any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your access into ApplicationManager.getApplication().runReadAction(...).

Please don't perform any long operations under this read action, as it delays all write actions, and it's not possible to type in editor while a read action is running.

Comment: thx 4 the answer. It works, but now there is the problem, that I have to wrap every single access into ApplicationManager.getApplication().runReadAction(...). I want for example highlight a psiElement in the Editor after receiving a message. With your solution I have to wrap nearly everything into it. And sometimes (for example when I want to access the selected Editor) it still shows the Error and I have to wrap it another time (I have to wrap it into the wrap ;))... Is there no alternative?

Comment: You can wrap a series of accesses in one read action, if it won't be too long.

Editor operations (e.g. adding a highlighting) would better be done on Swing thread, you can use Application.invokeLater for it.

Normally editor highlighting is performed from highlighting passes, e.g. from Annotator or inspections. I'd highly recommend to read plugin development guidelines at http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/PluginDevelopment